# Deleting row in Sqlite table

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-delete

I know it's been asked a million times but I still cannot get it to work. I'm trying to delete a row from my sqlite database but I keep getting an error. I'm sure it's to do with my syntax but I cannot get the correct syntax.

heres my delete method

```
public void deleteRouteNote(int notePosition){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    db.delete(TABLE_ROUTE_NOTE, COLUMN_NOTE + COLUMN_ROUTE_NOTE_POSITION + "where" + COLUMN_ROUTE_NOTE_POSITION + "=" + notePosition, null);

    db.close();
```

and the error I'm getting

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: routeNotewhererouteNotePosition (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM route_note WHERE routeNotewhererouteNotePosition=9
```

thanks for any help!!

EDIT:

Heres how I insert the data

```
  /////Add route note row to table
public void addRouteNote(RouteNote routeNote){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_NOTE, routeNote.get_routeNote());
    values.put(COLUMN_ROUTE_NOTE_POSITION, routeNote.get_routeNotePosition());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_ROUTE_NOTE , null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: please check whether you have column `routeNotewhererouteNotePosition`  exist and the sql is correct. please post sql here.

Comment: I edited my original post to show how Im inserting which works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
db.delete(TABLE_ROUTE_NOTE, COLUMN_ROUTE_NOTE_POSITION + " = " + notePosition, null)
```

Comment: I had tried this but its giving me strange results. Its as if it's deleting the value from the position column but not from the note column. Which is trowing the whole table out of sync

Comment: According to your question you said you want to delete `column where noteposition` .Now I am not sure why you want to use note column. Could you elaborate difference between note column and note position.

Comment: Maybe I worded it poorly. Note column has text in it and note position has an int in it.        So say it's like this: (string of text, 9 ) that would be a row. I want to delete both of them. When I tried it the way u suggested it deletes the 9 but not the string of text.

Comment: So I got it to work this is the correct answer. It turned out to be how I was using the table after it was added that was affecting it not how I was deleting the rows. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])),

> **table**     String: the table to delete from
>
> **whereClause**   String: the optional WHERE clause to apply when deleting. Passing null will delete all rows.
>
> **whereArgs**     String: You may include ?s in the where clause, which will be replaced by the values from whereArgs. The values will be
>   bound as Strings.

So according to this your delete clause might be something like this,

```
db.delete(TABLE_ROUTE_NOTE,COLUMN_ROUTE_NOTE_POSITION + "=? ,new String[]{notePosition});
```

Comment: I tried this but I'm getting an error because notePosition is an int not a string

Comment: @zsh5032 Wrap the `int` under `String.valueOf()`